# File picker. Import from another workbook's sheet

Tags: excel, vba, filepicker

I'm trying to create file picker to import sheet from another workbook. Workbook can be any path. Here is the code but something going wrong with file name. If anybody solved it before please help what's wrong here

```
Sub Main()
Dim fd As FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant
With fd
  .AllowMultiSelect = True
  If .Show = -1 Then
    For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      Dim path As String
      Dim file_name As String
      Workbooks.Open Filename:=path & file_name
      Set closedBook = Workbooks.Open("File_name As String")
      closedBook.Sheets("INPUT").Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
      closedBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      Worksheets("INPUT (2)").Visible = False
    Next
  Else
  End If
End With
Set fd = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is modified snippet from something I've used in the past. I'm not certain if FileDialogue works the same, but it's likely somewhat similar, so could probably be modified to work with it instead. Hopefully it helps.

```
Sub Main()
Dim dataFiles As Variant
Dim dataWorkbook As Workbook
Dim fileCount As Integer
    
    dataFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True)
    If IsArray(dataFiles) Then
        For fileCount = LBound(dataFiles) To UBound(dataFiles)
            Set dataWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(dataFiles(fileCount))
            'whatever you want to do here
            dataWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Next fileCount
    Else: Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```